# How to get a double random number and put its digits to variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a random double number (for example 4.58) 
and put its digits to three variables - 4 to the first variable, 5 to the second variable and 8 to the third variable.

Comment: I need it as double number , to design a program of how to convert meter

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/coyv3erf/2/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need this to be a floating-point number. Just create a three-digit number, convert it to a string, and split it into an array.

```
var numArr = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 900) + 100).toString().split('');
```

You can get at the numbers using the normal array method: `numArr[0]` etc.

To convert it to number, add a period in the first array position and then join it back to together:

```
numArr.splice(1, 0, '.');
var number = numArr.join('');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/coyv3erf/)

Alternatively, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) on how to create random floating-point numbers.

Comment: okay but , by this method i get 458 how to put (.) after (4) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var number = 4.26; // Your generated double number
output = []; // Array to store each digit
sNumber = number.toString(); // Convert the double to a string so we can split it

for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) 
{
    output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
}

console.log(output);
```

The output will be:

```
4, 2, 6
```

All numbers in JavaScript are doubles: that is, they are stored as 64-bit IEEE-754 doubles.

That is, the goal is not to get a "double": the goal is to get the string reprsentation of a number formatted as "YYY.XX". For that, consider Number.toFixed, for instance:

```
(100).toFixed(2)
```

The result is the string (not a "double"!) "100.00". The parenthesis are required to avoid a grammar ambiguity in this case (it could also have been written as 100.0.toFixed or 100..toFixed), but would not be required if 100 was in a variable.

Comment: thanks , but , how to get it randomly ? 
and put a (,) after the first number?

Comment: do you mean how to generate a random double from Math.Random();?

Comment: Yes, i need it double ,

Comment: but the users above , say  i can get a random number with 3-digit number
but i want to display it like this(4.58) for example

Comment: Andy has it right. Also just to note that all numbers generated in JS are Double :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this. I use `.replace(/[.]/g,"")` for removing  ".".

http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/coyv3erf/2/

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900) + 100;
numArr= randomNumber.toString().replace(/[.]/g,"").split("")
var number = numArr.join("");

console.log(numArr, number); // ["8", "4", "5"]  845
```

Comment: thanks :) 
the reason behind this question , is , i want to make an exercise  for children to compute the meter in unites , so if the child press "new problem" a random float number displayed in text , 
and if he press "solution button" i want to take the numbers of the float- number to show him the solution

Comment: @Oraib Abo Rob. I have edited my answer. There are three variables(randomNumber, numArr, number) for using

Comment: Accept correct answer, if find you answer. Otherwise,  explain it what you wish